Bootstrap Navbar not closing
I use bootstrap 5 and Angular 17. My navbar is opening but not closing anymore as soon as I add a toast. I found out that the problem might be on how I import bootstrap but I cannot find the issue. I installed bootstrap and popperjs.
"@popperjs/core": "^2.11.8",
"bootstrap": "^5.3.3",
Here is part of my angular.json:
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/@popperjs/core/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            ]

And here is part of my register component:
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Component, inject } from '@angular/core';
import {
  AbstractControl,
  FormBuilder,
  FormControl,
  FormGroup,
  ReactiveFormsModule,
  Validators,
} from '@angular/forms';
import { FooterComponent } from '../../../shared/components/footer/footer.component';
import { AuthenticationService } from '../../../core/services/authentication.service';
import { Toast } from 'bootstrap';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-register',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, ReactiveFormsModule, FooterComponent],
  templateUrl: './register.component.html',
  styleUrl: './register.component.scss',
})
export class RegisterComponent {
...

  showToastSignUpFailed() {
    const toastLiveExample = document.getElementById('liveToastSignUpFailed');
    if (toastLiveExample) {
      const toastBootstrap = Toast.getOrCreateInstance(toastLiveExample);
      toastBootstrap.show();
    }
  }
}

<div class="toast-container position-fixed bottom-0 end-0 p-3">
  <div
    id="liveToastSignUpFailed"
    class="toast"
    role="alert"
    aria-live="assertive"
    aria-atomic="true"
  >
    <div class="toast-header">
      <strong class="me-auto">didacto</strong>
      <button
        type="button"
        class="btn-close"
        data-bs-dismiss="toast"
        aria-label="Close"
      ></button>
    </div>
    <div class="toast-body">
      Irgendwas ist schief gelaufen. <br> {{ signUpError }}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

When I comment out the last two lines from the showToastSignUpFailed function the navbar works fine.
What am I doing wrong?
Thank you for your help!

do you have any errors in the console, and how are you calling showToastSignUpFailed

No errors in the console and the function is called onsubmit.

I found a workaround. The idea is to call the collapse function manually like this:
collapseNavbar() {
  const navbarCollapse = document.getElementById('navbarSupportedContent');
  if (navbarCollapse) {
    const bsCollapse = Collapse.getInstance(navbarCollapse) || new Collapse(navbarCollapse);
    bsCollapse.hide();
  }
}

Not the solution I was looking for but at least it works. If anyone knows how to solve the problem I am still happy to know the answer.
